# How can I group a set split by change in a field with respect to an order?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a set of records.

```
ID Value
1 a
2 b
3 b
4 b
5 a
6 a
7 b
8 b
```

And I would like to group them like so.

```
MIN(ID) MAX(ID) Value
1 1 a
2 4 b
5 6 a
7 8 b
```

I'm vaguely aware of oracle `over()` analytical function which looks to be the right direction, but I don't know what this problem is called much less how to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably an easier way, but this may help to start. I ran it on Postgres, but should work (maybe with a minor tweak) on Oracle. The inner most query puts the previous value on each row. We can use that to detect a grouping change (when value does not equal previous value). Every time there is a group change, we flag it with a "1". Sum these group changes and we now have a group id which increments every time there is a value change. Then we can perform our normal group by function.

```
create table x(id int, value varchar(1));

insert into x values(1, 'a');
insert into x values(2, 'b');
insert into x values(3, 'b');
insert into x values(4, 'b');
insert into x values(5, 'a');
insert into x values(6, 'a');
insert into x values(7, 'b');
insert into x values(8, 'b');


SELECT MIN(id), MAX(id), value
  FROM ( SELECT id
               ,value
               ,previous_value
               ,SUM( CASE WHEN value = previous_value THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ) OVER(ORDER BY id) AS group_id
           FROM ( SELECT id
                        ,value
                        ,COALESCE( LAG(value) OVER(ORDER BY id), value )  previous_value
                    FROM x
                    ORDER BY id
                ) y
       ) z
  GROUP BY group_id, value
  ORDER BY 1, 2;


 min | max | value
-----+-----+-------
   1 |   1 | a
   2 |   4 | b
   5 |   6 | a
   7 |   8 | b
(4 rows)
```

Comment: Does this type of problem have a name?

Comment: @wizard I'm not aware of any. This one was new to me (and an interesting puzzle). The idea of flagging rows with a zero or one and summing to partition groups seems to be a handy trick that comes into play every now and then, though.